# Make SWIG wrapped builtin class "hashable" in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, hashmap, swig

I use [SWIG](http://www.swig.org/) to expose our C++ libraries to Python. For performance reasons, I'm interested in switching some of the wrapping to use SWIG's [-builtin](http://www.swig.org/Doc3.0/SWIGDocumentation.html#Python_builtin_types) option, which removes the layers of Python proxy objects.

However, the wrapped class can no longer be used in Python sets or as a key in Python dicts. It is unhashable!

```py
>>> wrapped_object = WrappedObject()
>>> hash(wrapped_object)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unhashable type: 'structure.WrappedObject'
```

I have defined `__hash__()`, `__eq__()`, and `__ne__()` methods for my class.

```
>>> wrapped_object.__hash__
<built-in method __hash__ of structure.WrappedObject object at 0x7fa9e0e4c378>
>>> wrapped_object.__eq__
<method-wrapper '__eq__' of structure.WrappedObject object at 0x7fa9e0e4c378>
```

**What do I need to do to make this class hashable?**

Comment: Have you tried `%extend`'ing the class with a `__hash__` method? http://www.swig.org/Doc3.0/SWIGDocumentation.html#Python_nn43

Comment: I don't think you can `%extend%` a `builtin` class. They don't have any Python representation.

Comment: (and yes, I have tried that :) )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Builtin objects, Python uses the hash **slot** ([Python docs link](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/typeobj.html#c.PyTypeObject.tp_hash)) rather than the `__hash__()` method. Thus, the new builtin object needs to fill the hash slot. This requires a specific method prototype.

In the WrappedObject C++ files:

```cpp
long WrappedObject::getHash();
```

And in the SWIG wrapper definition files:

```
%rename(__hash__) WrappedObject::getHash;
%feature("python:slot", "tp_hash", functype="hashfunc") WrappedObject::getHash;
```

This worked for me!